# How to reduce the file size of production code Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using Angular-Cli with its default project.

I'm trying to get a production version of code, so I'm running --prod and at the output I see 911 KB, is it possible to optimize it further? And how can I tell angular to serve the gzip file?

> ng serve --prod

[image]

FYI: I tried ng serve --prod --aot but the server is building again in a loop. However, when I tried ng build --prod --aot then I see the size is reduced but I cannot start the server.

> ng build --prod --aot

[image]

Below is the code which I'm using in the Package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First, since all web servers now gzip output, your actual size is not the .js file size, but the .gz file size. That's the sole reason this file was created as I understand, to show you the realistic gzipped size.

However, there's room for better sizes, 40%+ improvement. If you install and use Angular CLI beta 16 for example (current version at time of writing), it has AoT compiler out of the box.

Run it like that:

```
ng build -prod --aot
```

As of beta-16 there're some issues with watch / serve and AoT at the moment though, like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2560), so you might for now only use it for actual production generation not dev server.

### Update:

Starting the next release after beta.26, `--aot` will be on by default when you use `-prod`.

It's currently [merged into master](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4105).

Comment: Hi Meligy, thank you for the answer, I already tried the build and serve and I have mentioned in my question as well. Is there a place we can have a watch for the update from angular team? Also, is it possible to server the pages from Angular cli after the ng build --prod --aot ?(but not using ng serve --prod --aot)

Comment: I also updated the question with the result for ng build --prod --aot

Comment: I don't think you can get much better than the 123 kB gzipped size at the moment. There are other tricks that can generate smaller bundle written and shown on the internet, for example, swapping uglify for google closure compiler, but the CLI doesn't take advantage of these yet. I know a core Webpack member is also a core CLI member and is probably planning to look into this, but it's not very soon.

Comment: Regarding how to keep updated, I personally open https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commits/master and subscribe to many issues in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues and also follow the Webpack guy on twitter https://twitter.com/TheLarkInn/